# Domino Designer: is there a way to set a default tab for a specific eclips view?

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

In Domino Designer there are several eclipse views consisting of multiple tabs; examples are the pop-up javaScript editor or the ssjs script library editor.

Is there a way to define a default tab for those editors or views?

For various reasons I'd like both editors to open the reference tab by default. Can this somehow be set somewhere inside the Preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've examined the Designer source and I can say with certainty that there is currently no way to control which tab gets opened by default in these editors.
However, I've made a note of this feature request and it may be addressed in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, not sure if it helps:

[image: check box]

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't help here... most probably the editors aren't considered to be eclipse views or whatever...